# How do you install TFS Command Line Tools for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I've installed visual studio 2017 enterprise and the new stand alone Team Explorer 2017.  There doesn't seem to be an option in either to add tfs command line tools or tfs shell integration.  [this](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2016/11/23/some-implications-of-the-new-modular-setup-of-visual-studio-2017-for-vsx-developers/) implies that it's an extension, but I haven't found anything on the visual studio marketplace.  I'd prefer not to reinstall 2015 to use the 2015 power tools, but there is no tf.exe anywhere on my box.

Comment: A typical installation of VS2017 Ent. puts tf.exe here: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe** Are you missing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [TFS 2017 RTW release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#a-idknownissues-aknown-issues), most of the previous Power Tools have been integrated into TFS 2017, that means no separate power tools, you don't need to install that separately. The Process Template Editor is one that has not been integrated, but you can get it in the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor).

> Visual Studio 2017 users: The tf.exe binary is no longer in a fixed
>   location in the Visual Studio install path as in previous releases
>   (for example, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE). Scripts using tf.exe should not hardcode a path to the file based on the Visual Studio 2017 install path.

Just as mentioned by Dave, the tf.exe should be under the path :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\{Version: Enterprise,Professional,Community}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsof‌​t\TeamFoundation\Tea‌​m Explorer\TF.exe
```

In most cases, you run the version control command in the context of a directory that is mapped in the workspace. For example, `$/SiteApp/Main/` is mapped to `c:\\code\\SiteApp\\Main\\`. To get the latest version of all items in the workspace:

```
c:\code\SiteApp\Main\SolutionA>tf get
```

Comment: @Miniver Cheevy Have you resolved your issue by above information?

Comment: it was operator error, I searched my hard drive using everything, which at some point in the past I had filtered to documents only, it was exactly where you said it was.